# Two formats in one view

Tags: views

Let me see if I can explain what I need.

1) I need some tabbed buttons listed first:

## View All | Category 1 | Category 2 | Category 3

2) For each button, clicking the tab should opens an area to display:

Other tabbed buttons (to the left).

### Current | Future | Past

Each of the buttons/views has a grid and a table display each (to the right).

#### Grid | List

Those are all views (example: Category 1 - Current - Grid format view, Category 1 - Current - Table format view).

I can probably use quicktabs module to display my top level tabs, but how to achieve #2?

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar using the module [Views Field View](https://drupal.org/project/views_field_view).

Module Page Description:

> This module allows you to embed a view as a field in a view. A new
>   field handler is made available, so this can also be used in area
>   (header/footer/empty) handlers as well as rows.
>
> This view handler can accept arguments from fields of the parent view
>   using tokens and pass them into the child view for each row. Raw or
>   rendered token values can be used, as well as static values.